# Mamp phpMyAdmin table query

Tags: mysql, mamp

I am having an issue were my code appears to be correct and am getting no errors querying or connecting to my database. "ErrorNumber 0:..."
But when i check phpMyAdmin it clearly has not queried. I have check all of my titles and table names, database name and everything is fine. My query will just not run or insert. here is my code:

```
  mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'aliendatabase');
   if (!$dbc) {
    die('Error connecting to MySQL server.' . mysql_error());
  }

  $query = "INSERT INTO aliens_abduction(first_name, last_name, when_it_happened, how_long, how_many, alien_description, what_they_did, fang_spotted, other, email)" .
    "VALUES('$first_name', '$last_name', '$when_it_happened', '$how_long', '$how_many', '$alien_description', '$what_they_did', '$fang_spotted', '$other', '$email')";

 mysql_query($query, $aliendatabase);
 echo "error number" . mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error() . "\n";

echo 'Connected Successfully';
  mysql_close($dbc);
```

Answer (score 0):

what is $dbc ?

It should rather be `$dbc = mysql_connect(...)` to test the connection.